# Has anyone experienced and overcome Reset this PC bitlockerRecoveryKeyError on MyAccoutMicrosoft.com

Tags: windows-10, recovery

On myaccount.microsoft.com/device-list and attempt to click show recovery key, the recovery key pops up for a fraction of a second and I get bitlockerRecoveryKeyError at the bottom of my browser window. I have tested this in Chrome and Edge on PC and Mac. I recorded the pop up with high speed video and the frame did not contain a code.

I am verified as admin on account by C name entry, I see the correct recovery key ID, the only hint of error is the quickly flashing empty pop up and error msg.

Any thoughts on the issue, is it unique, MS error or my issue?

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question, hopefully this will save someone some time.

It appears I was trapped in a legacy feature and really needed to be in https://aad.portal.azure.com/ and go into devices to get the bitlocker key. Not sure why the old site didn't tell you to move to the new one or why it even tempted me and allowed me to log in but the job is done.

So, if you're a newbie to windows admin like me, careful with older interfaces which must be kept alive to service legacy software.